Apple Silicon - Could not find module *** for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator, at: ***
 When I build an XCode project with the Apple Silicon chip, I have some issues. The project contains Pods and Swift Packages.I could not run the application at all and always got the following error:Could not find module xxx for target x86_64-apple-ios-simulator; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator, at: xxxI try to resolve this issue.

Always embed swift standard libraries = YES
Build Active Architure Only = YES
UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities = armv7
Excluded Architectures > Debug > Any iOS Simulator SDK arm64 add
Open Using Rosetta
Excluded Architectures > Debug > Any iOS Simulator SDK arm64 remove

However, issue always come to me.Do you have any solution for this problem?Thank you by advance!

Well if you wanna run in Rosetta, then you need the x86_64 version of the simulator packages.
